# Join list large list into a single tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of length 42 containing tibbles that I would like to join into a single tibble.

the way I would do it is:

```
full_join(list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]]...list[[42]])
```

I'm sure there's an easier way to do it, but I could not figure it out. can someone help?

Comment: Please try with `bind_rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tidyverse, you could use

```r
purrr::reduce(df_list, dplyr::full_join)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(full_join, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to combine lists of tibbles is with `list_rbind` (from `purrr`), and this also allows you to add in an id if you want to keep track of which list element everything came from (rather than just joined them all together and losing this information.)

```
list_rbind(list, names_to='element_number')
```

I have used this technique when reading in PDFs using `pdftools::pdf_data` (which returns a list of tibbles). So that I can keep the page numbers as well and just return one large tibble, I use:

```
pdftools::pdf_data(fname) |> 
  list_rbind(names_to='pagenum')
```